# Why when I use copy_from_user, some vague character added to original buffer?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I've created WRITE_IOCTL in kernel module and I call it in user mode:

```
ioctl(fd, WRITE_IOCTL, "Hello, Kernel!");
```

In kernel mode I have:

```
static int device_ioctl(struct file *filp,
    unsigned int cmd, unsigned long args) {
  char buff[14];

  switch (cmd) {
  case WRITE_IOCTL:
    copy_from_user( buff,(char *)args, 14);
    printk("This message received from User Space: %s\n", buff);
    break;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When I run this ioctl, I have some thing like theses in /var/log/kern.log :

```
This message received from User Space: Hello, Kernel!vE�
This message received from User Space: Hello, Kernel!M�
This message received from User Space: Hello, Kernel!M�
```

How can I solve this problem??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably `copy_from_user()` isn't putting the null-byte-terminattor because `args` is greater-or-equal than your `n` and `printk()` is expecting a null-terminatted one, so you're accessing garbage values. For solve that, initialize yourself `buf` to zeros:

```
  char buff[14 + 1] = {0}; // +1 for make room to 0-byte-terminattor.
```

It will fill all bytes of `buf` with zeros.

**EDIT:**

As @caf mentioned in comments, you need to left some space to null-byte-terminattor. So, instead of give exactly the buffer size to function, pass it n-1 so the function will loop untl `n` and then put the null-byte.

Comment: @Khajavi: Note that you also need to expand the buffer to size `[15]`, to make room for the null terminator.

Comment: @caf: Well, I fixed it.